# Apache POI set cell Font and font color

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am reading an `xlsx` file using XSSF of Apache POI. When reading the font of a particular cell and applying in new cell that font is applied for the whole sheet not for that perticular cell. i want for Example:

```
        column1 column2      column3 
row1    ARIAL   TIMES ROMAN  ARIAL

row2    TIMES ROMAN ARIAL   ARIAL   

row3     ARIAL   ARIAL   ARIAL
```

I want the same font in each cell that was in original file.

My code is:

```
public XSSFCellStyle setFontOnCell(XSSFCellStyle cellStyle, XSSFCell cell)
    {
        try {
            font = cell.getCellStyle().getFont();
            new_font.setFontName(font.getFontName());
            new_font.setBoldweight(font.getBoldweight());
            new_font.setFontHeight((short)font.getFontHeight());
            new_font.setFamily(font.getFamily());
            cellStyle.setFont(new_font);
            return cellStyle;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return cellStyle;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `new_font` seems to be a global variable, and you keep changing it and then injecting it into cells. It should be local to `setFontOneCell()` so that each cell gets its own `Font` instance, instead of all of them actually using the same object,

Comment: thank you Kilian Foth
 now its working but how can i destroy that object after applying style because its getting heap space error.

Comment: You need to keep that object around until the spread sheet you're constructing has been safely written ti disk. The easy solution is to increase your runtime heap memory size with the command-line switch -Xmx. If you actually want to save memory in your program, you could create a *cache* of `Font` objects so that you reuse instances as long as they're all for the same font, and create a new object only when you need a new font that didn't come up before.